# Retrieve all documents of my collection with firestore PHP

Tags: php

Hello I have the following database in firestore, and this code where I get the documents of the "ride" collection.

[image]

```
$db = new FirestoreClient([
     'projectId' => 'taxi-17b9c',
   ]);

$citiesRef = $db->collection('ride');
$documents = $citiesRef->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
        print json_encode($document->data(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
```

Basically my question is: why when I do a return of `$document-> data()`, I have only the json of a single document, but when I do `print_r ($document-> data())` or `json_encode ($document-> data())`, the information is complete.

What I want is to iterate over the "ride" collection and obtain in json format the data of the documents that I have.

What do I need to add?
Thank you!
Cheers!

Comment: Why many of your recent questions left as "open/marked unsolved"?

Comment: Some of my questions have not been resolved because they are still open to me. Is it necessary to close them in order to ask? An apology I will erase in a moment this question and I will close my other questions.

Comment: Oh, I see and understand, thanks.

Comment: Where do you use the "return"? Maybe I get it wrong but if your code snippet is in a function or on the php server site and you only replace print to return, your function will return the first document->data `json_encode($document->data(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`. and that's it. I guess, you have to collect the existing documents and return it as "one" json object at the end of your php function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is your server php code and you have only replaced "print" with "return", your function will only return `data()` of one existing `$document` and in your case only the `data()` of the first existing `$document`.

If this is all of your code, you can try to replace "print" with ["echo"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php):

```php
$db = new FirestoreClient([
     'projectId' => 'taxi-17b9c',
   ]);

$citiesRef = $db->collection('ride');
$documents = $citiesRef->documents();
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    if ($document->exists()) {
        echo json_encode($document->data(), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
```

You can also collect your existing `$document` in a new object or array in order to return it as one string, as shown in the following simple examples.

### Additional "simple" examples

```php
<?php
$testObjs = array(
    'object1' => array('info'=>'taxi-17b9c', "foo"=>"bar"),
    'object2' => array('info'=>'taxi-17b9c'),
    'object3' => array('info'=>'taxi-23', "foo"=>"bla")
   );

echo "echo as single object strings: \n";
foreach ($testObjs as $obj) {
    if(isset($obj["foo"])){
        echo json_encode($obj, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}


echo "\nexample return as one string array: \n";
echo showReturn($testObjs);

function showReturn($testObjs){
    $new_testObjs = array();
    foreach ($testObjs as $obj) {
        if(isset($obj["foo"])){
            array_push($new_testObjs, $obj);
        }
    }
    return json_encode($new_testObjs, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```